# Nemerle for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, nemerle

I just started to study Nemerle. Since this is .NET language, I wonder, is possible to use for Windows Phone development? Does Visual Studio support it **well**?

Comment: There is a [vs plug-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d93dc0a-0ce9-4b97-970c-ab1993eb934a) to enable Visual Studio integration for Nemerle. I am not sure if anyone has made Nemerle-specific WP project templates. You could try search in the VS gallery but I don't know if it's that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nemerle compiler uses System.Reflection.Emit for assembly manipulations. Then it can create  assemblies same CLR version only.

I know only one reciepe for build WP assemblies: ildasm ncc.exe, fix all references to WP framework and ilasm it again.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible, since Windows Phone runs a subset of the full .NET Framework which is closer to the .NET Compact Framework.

Looking at [this page](https://code.google.com/p/nemerle-2/wiki/Nemerle2) (translated from Russian) it looks like Compact Framework support is something that is/was planned for Nemerle version 2. However that article was written before Jetbrains acquired the project, so objectives may have changed.

Having said that, much more recently (Feb 2013) one of the Nemerle developers [spoke about](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d1880ec-e872-4258-b857-50c950f57094/portable-libraries-and-clr-fragmentation-becoming-more-and-more-of-an-issue) their difficulties in getting Nemerle to support other frameworks. So perhaps it is on their agenda after all.

Comment: seems like Nemerle becomes dead.

Comment: @MariusKavansky Nemerle is certanly *not* dead. What would give you that impression? As I said in my answer, JetBrains (one of the worlds leading IDE & development tools companies) acquired the project last year.

Comment: do you mean, the project of Nemerle language? JetBrains bought Nemerle?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Nemerle team focused on N2 project (programming language DSL). Next Nemerle version will be genereated by N2. Current version developed in bugfix mode https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/commits/master

Comment: @MariusKavansky I'm not sure if "bought" is the correct word. Perhaps "sponsored" is better. Jetbrains released [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/n2/) when they first acquired Nemerle.